# How to use proper syntax in where statement when updating a column where zip code columns are multiple

Tags: sql-server-2005, where-clause

I am assigning salespeople to a table column based on a zip code.  I want to include multiple zip codes in the where clause to set the sales person but don't know what the syntax is to do that.  Here is what I have.

```
update      [Customer]
set         [Territory Code] = 1
where       [Post Code] = '40205' and '40206' and '40118'
```

This, of course, does not work.

Comment: where [Post Code] in ( '40205', '40206', '40118')

Comment: Do you mean `OR` intead of `AND`?

Comment: Is this called an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use `IN`

```
where [Post Code] in ( '40205', '40206', '40118')
```